# Couldn't redirect to specific page using .htaccess rewriteRule when i'm using multiple parameters

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, .htaccess

My .htaccess lines are

```
RewriteRule ^notifications/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+) notifications.php?type=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^notifications/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+) notifications.php?type=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L]
```

Only first rewrite rule working even if i provided localhost/notifications/competative/upsc

throws error as undefined index 'cat' if i'm echoing it.

This one working fine localhost/notifications/competative/

Comment: you should have to use this var_dump(cat); after cat=$2 [NC,L] it shows that line is working properly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below rules, we are putting the '$' sign to indicate the boundary of our rule.

```
RewriteRule ^notifications/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ notifications.php?type=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^notifications/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ notifications.php?type=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L]
```